How do I instrument and configure a django app with OTel?
I created a sample django app that accepts to endpoint.
My goal is to instrument it with OTel so that it will report the following metrics for each endpoint:

Error rate
Latency

(And hopefully to do so without explicitly set each endpoint with specific code.)
I tried OpenTelemetry WSGI Instrumentation but I couldn't find how to configure it to export metrics to the OTel collector.
Is the WSGI instrumentation suppose to accompany the OTEL instrumentation? Do I need to instrument my code with both to be able to configure it?
In short, my question is how do I configure the OTel instrumentation to export the above metrics to the OTel collector or Prometheus endpoint?

Expand on what you've tried and what specifically isn't working. The link you shared has specific Django instructions - did you follow those, and if so, what happened?
